# android activity download files

Tags: java, android, download

i'm trying to use this to download mp3 files

```
Intent downloadIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( "http://www.xxx.com/1.mp3"));
```

but it always opens another application to play this mp3 file....

i only want to download it ,how can i do ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use another application for this, as you will leave your own app.

You should open a HttpRequest by yourself, download the file and then process it.

Check these links:

- http://www.tutorials-android.com/learn/How_to_post_a_non_blocking_HTTP_request_in_Android.rhtml
- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/HttpRequest.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a new thread to fetch the the file (or your UI will be frozen while the file is being downloaded)

Then instead of intenting URI, use BufferedInputStream to do it.